# Terminal Services printing

Tags: windows-server-2003, terminal-server

We are using a hosted terminal server to run some applications on.

We have three users who connect to the server through RDP and try to print to a networked printer called: HP Photosmart C7280.

One of the users is using Windows XP Pro 32-bit on the host and when they print through the terminal server it works fine.

Another one of the users is using Vista 32-bit on the host and when they print through the terminal server it works fine.

The third user is using Windows 7 64-bit on the host and when they print through the terminal server it only print the first line of the page (A test page print 3/4s of the test page compared to printing all of the page when using the other 2 machines).

We are only printing from Word 2007 and Excel 2007 on all machines.

The server is Windows 2003. No errors in the event log.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also try TSPrint from terminalworks. Their application isn't as expensive.
http://www.terminalworks.com/tsprint.php

Answer (score 1):

Printing from a terminal server, particularly 2k3 servers, is always a hassle.

I don't have advice for this particular scenario, but I can share my experiences.

We found after having problem after problem with 150 users in different locations with different printers, and having spoolers crash etc, that we would offload our printing to one of two solutions:

- [ThinPrint](http://www.thinprint.com/)
- [Screwdrivers](http://www.tricerat.com/screwdrivers)

We went with ThinPrint, simply because it was the one we had more experience with, and since doing it we've not had any trouble with printing on any clients, at all.

(careful with older versions of thinprint though, as installing .NET 3.0 will kill the entire system - we found this out the hard way and had to rebuild 4 terminal servers)

Comment: Thanks for this. Do you know how much these apps cost? as I don't have much budget because the server only supports 3 users.

Comment: They're pricey, but I wasn't involved in the purchasing of the licenses so I honestly don't know. We went with the .print queue manager I think, which was the cheapest one, but it was still a few grand (I think)

Answer (score 0):

If it's not been done already, load the x32 2003 drivers directly onto the terminal server. It will then pick that driver up and use it when printing for clients.

Comment: the 32-bit drivers are installed as this works from Windows Xp and Vista.

Comment: Ah, then possibly I'm on the wrong end of the stick here. Are the x64 drivers loaded on the 2003 box as an alternative driver?